# Name of class as static variable

Tags: swift

I can print class name of an instance.

```swift
final class SomeSome {
    var description: String { 
        return "\(type(of: self))" 
    }
}
```

What is the best practice to obtain such value as static in Swift 5?

```swift
final class SomeSome {
    static var description: String { 
        return ????
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is the "best practice", but you can do something like `String(describing: self)` or just `"\(self)"`

Answer (score 0):

The string interpolation you show is ultimately calling `String(describing: type(of: self))`.

You can do the same thing in the static context with `String(describing: self)`, where `self` is the metatype object, in this context, `SomeSome.self`.